# How do I reapply all the styles in Word?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I have a Word document with styles. I want to reapply the styles based on the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [here](http://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/modifyastyle.html)

If you're using Word 95, 97 or 2000:

1. From the main menu, Format > Style.
2. In the Styles list, choose the style you want to Modify. If you can't find the style you want to modify, in the Category box, choose "All Styles". (Tip: You can see a description of the style below the Preview.)
3. Click Modify. You're now at the Modify Style dialog.

If you're using Microsoft Word 2002 or Word 2003:

1. From the main menu, Format > Styles and Formatting.
2. In the panel, find the style you want to Modify. (Note: If you don't see the style listed, under Show, choose All Styles. If you still don't see your style listed, under Show, click Custom, tick your style and click OK. Then, choose All Styles.)
3. Right-click on the style name and choose Modify. You're now at the Modify Style dialog.

Comment: This reply doesn't answer the question! Joshua wants to reapply the styles not modify them. I actually do have the same question, but am not satisfied by this answer!