# Powerpoint - switch font weight to bold instead using faux bold; then apply to single characters

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm supposed to modify an existing PPT presentation, create a master for it etc.

In the current presentation, it is possible in some text boxes to **switch any character to bold**, without switching the rest of the paragraph, plus it will also **use the correct font weight for bold** instead of creating a faux bold style.

Trying to recreate this in a **new presentation from scratch** on a master seems impossible. I can at best switch the etire paragraph to bold or apply an ugly faux bold style.
I read about using VDB script, but I can't expect an entire company to allow scripts and click off 10 warning popups, and the old presentation definitely isn't using any scripts.

Since I'm used to work with professional DTP software, it's really hard for me to find my way in MS Office (still using Word instead of HTML in Outlook - in 2023, seriously?). There is no way to check text properties. No info in MS Office online,  **Office Help just produces an error** (!)

Please, I want this of my desk. I, for now, copied the modifiable text objects to the master and deleted the rest, but I can't believe it's not possible (according to MS...), since **apparently it is**!

Possible:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0UWj.png)

Not possible:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p63M5.png)

Comment: Perhaps original was created in LibreOffice Impress. Impress can create PPT or PPTX documents and *POTX templates*, usable in MS PowerPoint. BTW, avoid rants -- calling software "junk", whether it is or is not, won't help get an answer.

Comment: You've asked the same question in MS Answers and have several replies there. By the way, the fact that PowerPoint (which is NOT a DTP program) doesn't behave like a DTP program is more a failure of your expectations than of the software.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks for alerting me, I didn't see any answer on MS until now.
It's definitely a failure of my expectation to assume this, based on the fact that Office is so backwards I wonder it hasn't been redesigned properly yet. Things that should be quick & easy are way too complicated to achieve, but can be achieved. It's like putting gears on a bike, but no shifting lever. You just have to stop, take a piece of paper, take the chain, move it and get back on the bike

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I removed the rant part - though I still firmly bekieve it to be true.
The file was created by an agency, and in the company OpenOffice is out of question. It all just seems utterly illogical to me and is very frustrating - please forgive my ranting.

Comment: >> "based on the fact that Office is so backwards" ... Or your expectations are. Let's leave the (IMO) unfounded criticism aside and do what we can to address the *problem*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something here, but it seems that you are comparing two different scenarios. In the old document, you are making single words bold outside of the Master and in the new document, you are trying to make single words bold inside the Master. Is that correct?

This behaviour actually makes sense, since the paragraphs in the Master are only placeholders. And if that placeholder paragraph would have a mix between standard and bold style, then how would PPT know which style it should apply once the "real" text is entered? It can either format it without any bold styling or it can add the bold styling. But it cannot guess which words of the newly entered sentence should be made bold.

Comment: Well put, and exactly correct.

Comment: My main concern was/is, how I can get PPT to use a bold font face instead a faux bold style (making letters appear bold, but not using the bold font weight). 
In the old document, this works for some reason, in the new, created from scratch, it doesn't, even though the same fonts are set in the document style XML.
I do understand that master text is just a placeholder. BUT using that placeholder, I get wrong font size, wrong indentation, basing the new presentation on the file of the old one now miraculously works with free formatting of text, but also lets you choose any font.

Comment: @Corniger Usually the "real" bold font will be used, if the bold font style is correctly installed on the system within the same font group of the non-bold font (see https://superuser.com/questions/577947/use-a-different-font-for-bold-text-instead-of-synthetic-bold). It could be that it works in the old PPT, since the fonts have been embedded into that PPT.  Go to File > Options > Save and check if the checkbox is set for embedding fonts.

Comment: Yes, I personally set it to embed, though - it doesn't. I just presented the slides in a screencast and all of a sudden, today all bold text was faux bold, partly unreadable and I had to replace the faux bold style for every bold item again. Maybe because I had Word open at the same time, I can't tell. Imo - very erratic. On the other hand - I know very little about MS Office.

I think the marketing department will have to teach users not to use the "bold" button, like they tried. I can already see this going all kinds of wrong...